# Python: Conditioning on an Attribute of an Object that may not Exist

Tags: python

I had a bit of conditional code that looked like this:

```
if self.above and self.above.author and self.above.author.username!=self.author.username:
    "notify above.author that someone has replied to their comment"
```

But if there is no `self.above` or if either of the comments has no author then I get an error like:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

so I can check first before looking for those attributes

```
if self.above:
    if self.above.author:
        if self.author:
            if self.author.username!=self.above.author.username:
                "notify about response"
        else:
            "notify about response"
```

but with all the extra ifs and the duplication of the "notify about response" code, the number of lines is more than doubled. There are a lot of times when this problem arises, so if I use the above solution it's going to mean fifty extra lines of code to check a few simple conditions.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor all the object attribute lookups out into a function that handles the missing attributes gracefully. If `self.above.author.username` is missing, that's the same situation as `self.above` being missing as far as you're concerned -- you don't care *where* you ran out of runway, just that you did at some point.

```
def resolve(obj, path):
    """Resolves an attribute path on an object, returning `None` 
       if any attribute is not found"""
    for name in path.split("."):
        obj = getattr(obj, name, None)
        if obj is None:
            break
    return obj

selfauthor  = resolve(self, "author.username")
aboveauthor = resolve(self, "above.author.username")

if not selfauthor or (selfauthor and selfauthor != aboveauthor):
    "notify about response"
```

You can even put the `resolve()` method somewhere on a base class, then it's a nicer:

```
self.resolve("above.author.username")   # etc
```

Comment: Unless there is some greater wisdom that I am missing this looks like just a [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)ilistic way of doing exception handling and therefore I am inclined to downvote.

Comment: this part `self.above.author.username!=self.author.username` is checking that the username values are not the same, your `resolve` function does not return these values.

Comment: Very nice. This allows me to get exactly the behavior I originally wanted. Well written. Thanks.

Comment: @Kimvais My intent was to duplicate pretty much exactly the conditions under which the notifications would be sent from the original code. This would be kinda hard to do by catching exceptions (probably even more complicated than the original code). There's nothing wrong with letting `getattr()` handle the exception, that's why it has the optional third argument.

Comment: Fixed a bug, it was pretty late when I posted that.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try [handling the AtributeError](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) instead. Also, you want to make the "notify about response" code a function, so you don't have to duplicate the code there. e.g:

```
def notify(who, about_what):
    "notify who that about_what happened"

try:
    if self.above.author.username!=self.author.username:
        notify(self.above.author.username, "someone replied to a comment")
except AttributeError:
    notify(someone, "something went wrong")
```

Also, you want to make the "notify about response" code a function, so you don't have to duplicate the code there.

Comment: how is that better than an 'if' statement?

Comment: @WeaselFox you only have to handle it once (instead of nested if's). This is consistent with python's duck-typing paradigm - http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing

Comment: @WeaselFox Plus, in Python it's preferable to use exceptions rather than if statements. It's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: @Hamish - more accurately it's "EAFP"-principle, not duck-typing.

Comment: But an error is not indicative of whether or not the notification should actually be sent. There are multiple ways for the condition to fail. If it was because the above comment was left anonymously, then there's no need to send a notification. If it was because the current comment was left anonymously, then a notification should still be sent. So, after the exception is caught, there would still need to be some follow up code to decide whether to do the notification.